# Convert matrix of pixels into image

Tags: java

I want to convert this matrix into its original image that I have structured from.
I want to know the simplest way to do so.

`int pixels[width][height];  //Filled with pixels of colored image(jpg)`

Comment: How exactly do you desire to obtain this image? Could you provide an example of the usage of the obtained image?

Comment: I just want to know if I have built the matrix right by reconstructing the original image. It's just a test.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder how you going to manage color codes from int type.

Anyways, i think code will be like this. did not tested it

```
BufferedImage image;
for(int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<pixels[i].length; j++) {
        int a = pixels[i][j];
        Color newColor = new Color(R,G,B);
        image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps